# Segmentation fault in my NASM program(I need a bit of help)

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm, multidimensional-array

My program produces a segmentation fault and as a result will not print the lowest number from my array. I went over my program with my TA but she only told me that the cause of the segmentation fault was probably an array out of bound exception. I need a little help spotting where I went wrong if anyone would be so kind.

```
section .data                                       ; initilized data segment
matrixA dd  79, 98, 58, 62, 94                      ; 5x5 matrix
        dd  82, 92, 76, 51, 81
        dd  83, 46, 67, 71, 52
        dd  43, 61, 73, 44, 48
        dd  59, 85, 82, 66, 89

msgLow db 'The lowest Value of the Matrix is:', 0x0a ; Lowest Message
lenLow equ $- msgLow


section .bss                                        ; uninitialized data segment
;...

section .text                                       ; program data
global _start                                       ; global scope
_start:                                             ; main function


printMsg:                                           ; Prints msgLow
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, msgLow
mov edx, lenLow
int 0x80

init:
mov edi, 0                                      ; used to track row position
mov esi, 0                                      ; added to edi give a number in the matrixA
mov ecx, 99                                     ; upper limit of lowest number

call outter                                     ; sub routine for finding lowest number

mov eax, 4                                      ; Prints out the lowest number 
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, esp
add [ecx], DWORD 48             
mov edx, 4

exit:                                           ; Program Exit
mov eax, 1
xor ebx, ebx
int 0x80
;Exit

;Function Start                                 ; Function for finding lowest value
outter:                                         ; Compare Main
cmp edi, 96                                     ; 
ja  funct_end                                   ; end the function at edi => 100
mov esi, 0                                      ; initialize esi when this part of loop is run    

inner:
cmp esi, 4                                      ; Compare esi (inner loop index) to 5
ja inner_end                                    ; ends inner loop if > 4 esi's limit 
mov eax, [matrixA + edi + esi * 4]              ; moves element from  matrixA into eax
cmp eax, ecx                                    ; Compare eax element of matrixA to ecx
ja  higher                                      ; jump if value is above ecx value
mov ecx, eax                                    ; sets new lowest number if reached

higher:                                         ; Incrementer
inc esi                                         ; increments sdi
jmp inner

inner_end:                                      ; if outter give a higher value                             
add edi, 20                                     ; row is 5 x 4
jmp outter

funct_end:                                      ; end of function
push ecx
ret
;Function End
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very strange:

```
push ecx
ret
```

I guess you don't want the function to return to an address which is determined by `ECX`. Typically results of a function are returned in `EAX`. So change it to:

```
mov eax, ecx
ret
```

and handle it appropriate after `call outter`. Looking at the following lines I suggest:

```
call outter
push eax
```

It's a good idea to clear the stack, when that value isn't needed anymore (e.g. `POP`).

You won't become happy with your integer-ascii-conversion, look here or at Google for a better solution.